# Storing unstructured data for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nosql, nlp, nltk

I am doing an NLP term project and am analyzing over 100,000 news articles from this corpus. https://github.com/philipperemy/financial-news-dataset

I am looking to perform sentiment analysis on this dataset using NLTK. However, I am a bit confused about how this pipeline should look for storing and accessing all of these articles.

The articles are text files that I read and perform some preprocessing on in order to extract some metadata and extract the main article text. Currently, I am storing the data from each article in a python object such as this:

```
{
   'title' : title,
   'author' : author,
   'date' : date,
   'text' : text,
}
```

I would like to store these objects in a database so I don't have to read all of these files every time I want to do analysis. My problem is, I'm not really sure which database to use. I want to be able to use regexes on certain fields such as date and title so I can isolate documents by date and company names. I was thinking of going the NoSql route and using a DB like MongoDb or CouchDB or maybe even a search engine such as ElasticSearch.

After I query for the documents I want to use for analysis, I will tokenize the text, POS tag it, and perform NER using NLTK. I have already implemented this part of the pipeline. Is it smart to do this after the database is already indexed in the database? Or should I look at storing the processed data in the database well?

Finally, I will use this processed data to classify each article, using a trained model I've already developed. I already have a gold standard, so I will compare the classification against the gold standard.

Does this pipeline generally look correct? I don't have much experience with using large datasets like this.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for Elasticsearch. The tokenization and position tags and offsets come packaged with it.

Comment: It might also be overkill to set up a DB just for training data if you are not familiar with the technology. Reading in 100,000 text files will not be a serious time committment usually.

Comment: @patrick What if I want to be able to run queries on my dataset, thought? Wouldn't a DB be useful? Or should I just write my own script to do that?

Comment: you will not use regex for retrieve date in elastic. This kind of operations are natively supported. If you need to index the output of nltk ner you have to write a script for that